# Problema instalación Darshan

Tags: linux

Estoy instalando darshan en un linux Rocks, y para crear los directorios donde debería quedar el `log` de darshan estoy ingresando el siguiente comando:

```
$HOME/local/darshan/bin/darshan-mk-log-dirs.pl
```

Pero al ejecutarlo me arroja el siguiente error.

> Error: could not mkdir /darshan/log/2018.

Alguien sabe como puedo solucionarlo. Mil gracias.

Comment: si esto está tratando de crear una nueva carpeta en la raíz (cosa que no veo por qué alguien querría hacer), debes ejecutarlo como root. Antes de eso valida si no tienes que pasarle algún parámetro al script o hacer alguna configuración, porque la carpeta de logs debiera quedar, usualmente, dentro de `/var/log`, aunque puede variar entre distribuciones.

Comment: solo ejecuta esto antes de la instalacion: mkdir -p /darshan/log/2018 y dale permisos de chmod -R 777 el los cambiara una ves se instale